# R:How to Use cld Function to Get Results from One-Way Anova

Tags: r, anova, multcompview

So I have installed the *multcomp* and *multcompview* packages to RStudio; However, when I go to use the cld function I keep getting this error

```
Error in UseMethod("cld") : 
no applicable method for 'cld' applied to an object of class "data.frame"
```

My data is as follows:

```
Group1 <- c(12.4,10.7,11.9,11.0,12.4,12.3,13.0,12.5,11.2,11.1)
Group2 <- c(8.1,11.5,11.3,8.7,12.7,10.7,9.6,11.3,11.1,13.7)
Group3 <- c(8.5,11.6,10.2,10.9,9.0,9.6,9.9,11.3,10.5,14.2)
Group4 <- c(8.7,9.3,8.2,8.3,9.0,9.4,9.2,12.2,8.5,12.9)
Group5 <- c(12.7,13.2,11.8,11.9,12.2,11.2,13.7,11.8,11.5,9.7)

Combined_Groups<-data.frame(cbind(Group1,Group2,Group3,Group4,Group5))
Combined_Groups #shows spreadsheet like results
summary(Combined_Groups) #min, median, mean, max

Stacked_Groups <- stack(Combined_Groups)
Stacked_Groups #shows the table Stacked_Groups

Anova_Results<-aov(values~ind,data=Stacked_Groups)
summary(Anova_Results) #shows Anova_Results

qf (.95, df1=4, df2=45) #this gives you the critical mean of the F 
distribution

t(apply(Combined_Groups, 2, function(x) c(mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x), 
n=length(x)))) #table of mean,SD,n

tk <-TukeyHSD(Anova_Results)
tk

cld(Combined_Groups, sort = TRUE, by = NULL, Letters = 
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",alpha = 0.05)
```

What should the correct format of cld be? I want the results from to go from lowest to highest means and then the pairwise comparisons below it in letters.

Comment: (this isn't an answer to question, but use `data.frame(group1, etc..)` instead of `data.frame(cbind(`).

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Do you mind explaining why that is better? I am new to R and that was the example I saw online that I have been following.

Comment: You'd run into issues if some of the variables were not numeric, as `cbind` makes a matrix and therefore coerces all variables to a common type.

Comment: So then `cbind` is good for numeric data, but when you have nominal variables it is better to not include it. I gather based on your advice it is good practice to not use `cbind`. Also, the change should not effect the rest of the code correct? Thank you for your clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cld` is in the `multcomp` package. Reading `?cld` gives a clear example of usage with `aov`. It uses `glht`, not `TukeyHSD`. Here is how it works in your example:

```
library(multcomp)
ph <- glht(Anova_Results, linfct = mcp(ind = "Tukey"))
cld(ph)
```

Gives:

> ```
> Group1 Group2 Group3 Group4 Group5 
>    "b"   "ab"   "ab"    "a"    "b"
> ```